# D3 Race condition between databinding and drag raise

Tags: d3.js

In my `d3` graph, I have a list of vertices that I want to render along with a force simulation attached, as well as drag behavior for vertices. This works fine. However, since the vertices can overlap, I want to change the drag mechanism such that the dragged vertex becomes the top-most SVG element during the drag operation. I accomplished this by updating the drag started callback like so and assigning this behavior to each vertex created:

```
const fnDrag = drag()
  .on('start', function(d: Data) {
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    select(select(this).node().parentNode).raise();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
    ...
  })
  .on('drag', ...)
  .on('end', ...);
```

The problem is that the simulation's `tick` callback is defined like so:

```
const simulation = forceSimulation(data)
  .force('...', ...)
  .force('...', ...)
  .on('tick', () => {
    vertexElements.selectAll('g')
      .data(data, d => d.key)
      .join(
        enter => {
          return enter.append('g');
        },
        update => {
          return update.attr('translate', d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        },
        exit => {
          return exit.remove();
        }
      );
  });
```

And this causes some sort of race condition between the dragStarted callback and the onTick callback. The dragStarted callback raises the dragged SVG element to be the last element of the parent, while the onTick callback renders the `data` array such that the SVG elements are rendered in the order given in the input array (ie. not raised).

I have verified this by inspecting the element hierarchy in Chrome and I see that during drag, the dragged element vary rapidly toggles places with its order dictated by the input array and the last child.

How do I go about implementing the raise functionality correctly? Do I have to resort to manually modifying the input array in the dragStarted handler so that the dragged element data is the last item in the list? This seems like a bad idea. Also, I would want the Z-order to return to its initial state after dragging is stopped.

I've tried keeping dragging state in the vertices data structure too, set and unset the flag during dragStart and dragEnd callbacks, and using `selection.sort((a, b) => a.dragging ? +1 : -1)` in the onTick handler to force dragged vertices at the end of the drawing loop, but this doesn't render anything at all. The selection apparently becomes empty.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to check for the drag state in the update method of the tick, and raise it there as well:

```js
    update => {
        update.attr('translate', d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        update.each((d, i, nodes) => {
         if(d.dragging) {
           select(nodes[i].parentNode).raise()
         }
        })
    },
```

Comment: Hi. Tried that, but it doesn't change the drawing order. :(

Comment: Is the drag behavior attached to a <circle> inside the <g> and you call `parentNode` to raise the <g> when <circle> is dragged? If so,  the `nodes[i].parentNode` in my snippet should be `nodes[i]`, because it is already selecting the <g>. Could you try? (although I'm not certain this is why it didn't work)